# TLS/SSL certificate verification

Tags: ssl, gnutls

I am new to TLS/SSL so this might be a very basic question, but I've been searching a lot an could not find an answer.

I am trying to implement a TLS/SSL client. This client will run on an embedded unit with Windows OS on it (XPe or WES7). My implementation uses GnuTLS.

How do I get the list of trusted authorities to my unit so my client can verify the server's certificate? Is it supposed to be a file stored on the client side, that the client is responsible for keeping up to date? Or can my client somehow get this list from the internet each time it is needed and not maintain it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Certificating Authority (CA) master certificates are stored client side and the client is responsible for keeping them up to date.  Keeping them up to date isn't as hard as it sounds, as CA certificates aren't changed that often - most are valid for 5-10 years at least.

Client side storage is necessary because any given internet site your application uses might be compromised.

To get a list, you might start by looking at the CA certificates distributed with a browser or at the cacerts file distributed with Java.  Before releasing your code, you'll probably want to check that the certs you use are genuine by checking them against information provided by the CA.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. If my client is responsible for sending emails, what would be the right way to go about creating the list? Will I need to manually add every single email provider?

Comment: Email works differently.  Email servers talk to each other, so the client only needs to know about one email server.

Comment: So... basically what you are saying is that I need to keep only one certificate on my client? For example if I only keep google's certificate will it be able to send an email to yahoo? Where should I go to check for genuine certificate for google? Based on my browser info their cert comes from Usertrust, but I don't see how I can get if from there. Sorry, I know those questions are very basic. There is so much info about it online and I've been reading a lot of it recently, but it appears to be very hard to find answers to these small questions.

Comment: What is your client a client of - email, web, something else?

Comment: It is an embedded system that does many things,but now it also needs to send an emails.The key point is that it is an emb. system,meaning that it is a stripped down system that wouldn't allow to do things a person would normally do on Windows,like internet browsing,installing software etc.The system is connected to network.As a developer,I need to find the right way to maintain cert file on such unit.It looks like it will have to be a local file with certs.For now it seems like I need only email providers certs,but I would would want it work in a generic way to allow future development.

Answer (score 0):

Go to any Windows machine and run "certman.msc" from command-line.  Export each CA certificate (Intermediate Certificates, Trusted Authorities) to file (BER, PEM), then import these certificates into your embedded software.   Now you can validate email certificates, the same way Windows does (i.e. using various x.509 related RFCs and CRLs)